# jQuery: hasClass partial match

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, selector, cpu-word

When using [Attribute Contains Word Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) is it supposed to evaluate to true? I'm trying to use it in an if/else statement like the one below and it is not evaluating to true.

```
<li class="orange blue">
    <div class="answer">Some Content</div>
</li>
<input type="button" name="yellow" value="yellow" class="yellow" />
<br />
<input type="text" value="" class="result" />

$("input.yellow").click(function() {
    if ( $("div.answer").parent().hasClass($("[class~='bl']")) == true ){
        $("input.result").val("has class");
    } else {
        $("div.answer").parent().addClass("blue");
        $("input.result").val("class added")
    };
});
```

[The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CoderLevel1/c4z7yn2L/21/)

Comment: Uh, hasClass takes a string.  Your giving it a jQuery object.

Comment: You might consider using filter().length instead.  Or is().   .is("[class~='bl']")

Comment: Oh thanks, I will try that. I am new to jQuery/javascript.

Comment: In that case I might also comment that hasClass() and is() both return a boolean true/false, so it is not necessary to do == true

Answer (score 2):

As the comment advised, `hasClass` takes in a `string`. so you could use `is`:-

```
if ( $("div.answer").parent().is($("[class~='bl']"))){
```

or you could create a little jquery plugin:-

```
$.fn.hasPartialClass = function(partial){
  return new RegExp(partial).test(this.prop('class')); 
};
```

and use like:-

```
if ( $("div.answer").parent().hasPartialClass("bl")){
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot that you are using the "Attribute Contains **Word** Selector"
So for this selector to match you have to use `[class~='blue']`. 
You can't use `[class~='bl']`, because the class attribute does'nt contain the word 'bl' but the word 'blue'.

The way to use this selector :

```
    $("input.yellow").click(function() {
    if ( $("div.answer").parent().is("[class~='blue']") ){
        $("input.result").val("has class");
    } else {
        $("div.answer").parent().addClass("blue");
        $("input.result").val("class added")
    };
});
```